# Leaflet Locate current location

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, html

I'm new to Leaflet and anything web related. I have got the following map working which asks for your location and changes the map view to that location. That is great but then the map continues to snap back to that location once you have panned round.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/leaflet-gesture-handling.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="../dist/leaflet-gesture-handling.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p><a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">© MapTiler</a>, Contains OS data © Crown copyright and database right 2019</p>
    <script>
      var map = L.map("map", {
        centre: [51.450584 , -2.5946832],
        zoom: 12,
        gestureHandling: true
        });
      L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/uk-openzoomstack-light/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=JRDKWZ623VwZMdOklau8',{
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        minZoom: 4,
        attribution: "\u003ca href=\"https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; MapTiler\u003c/a\u003e, Contains OS data \u00a9 Crown copyright and database right 2021",
        crossOrigin: true
        }).addTo(map);
      map.locate({setView: true, watch: true})
        .on('locationerror', function(e){
            console.log(e);
            alert("Location access has been denied.");
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After eventually making sense of the Leaflet documentation it states the `watch` option if `true`, starts continuous watching of location changes (instead of detecting it once) using W3C `watchPosition` method. You can later stop watching using `map.stopLocate()` method.

I made the changes below removing the `watch: true`.

```
map.locate({setView: true})
        .on('locationerror', function(e){
            console.log(e);
            alert("Location access has been denied.");
        });
```